# How to add the automatic generated id to the cloud Firestore database

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

This is my hash map, it is not adding the actual generated id

```
    val user = hashMapOf(
        "deviceToker" to " ",
        "dob" to date.text.toString(),
        "email" to email_reg.text.toString(),
        "id" to db.collection("patients").document().id,
        "name" to name.text.toString()
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the randomly generated ID of a document to the contents of the document itself, first just call `document()` with no parameters to get a reference to the document that doesn't exist yet:

```
val ref = db.collection("patients").document()
```

Then use that reference to both add the ID to the document contents:

```
val user = hashMapOf(
    "deviceToker" to " ",
    "dob" to date.text.toString(),
    "email" to email_reg.text.toString(),
    "id" to ref.id,   // note the use of ref.id here to get the random id
    "name" to name.text.toString()
)
```

Now add the document using the same referece:

```
ref.set(user)  // be sure to check for errors
```

As you can see, the ID is generated on the client, not on the server.

Comment: Hey Doug. Wouldn't be more appropriate to use `db.collection("patients").document(ref.id).set(user)`? When using `.add(user)`, a new id is generated and in such case, the id of the document will be different than the id that exists in the document itself.

Comment: @AlexMamo Actually just `ref.set(user)`. No need to create a new ref for this.

Comment: `ref` is a `DocumentReference` object. If we don't pass the `id` to the `document()` method, a new id is generated. So the id of the document will be different than the id that exists in the document itself. Basically is the same thing as using `add()` on a `CollectionReference` object. That's why I suggested passing `ref.id` as an argument.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, the question is asking how to put the generated ID of the document within the doucment itself.  This a fairly common thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the procedure you are using isn't right. From the docs:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
val newCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();

// later...
newCityRef.set(data);
```

So the way I go about it:

- Create the ref to the doc first.
- Then set the data into the doc ref.

Comment: I think you pasted the code from a sample that was not Kotlin.

Comment: I think the diff is "val" vs. "var" (I edited), but otherwise it's identical. What's important is the API procedure correction. I see another answer posted the same thing I did; create the reference/doc first, then set the data into it. He adds the detail of the ref.id, which is good, but the gist is the same.

Comment: It's not - the java and kotlin APIs use "document()" instead of "doc()".

Comment: By changing an "r" to an "l", and "doc" to "document", I otherwise gave the correct answer; the problem was you weren't going about the sequence correctly. I would assume most coders could work with that, I apologize if I was wrong in this instance.